# Enabling malloc stack logging in debugger leads to memory issues

Tags: xcode, debugging, memory-management, malloc

Wondering if others have experienced this as well in Xcode: my app seems to have no crash issues when running normally OR in Instruments (Allocations) but if I run it from the debugger on my phone it will eventually (after ~10 rounds in my game) crash due to memory error (no other information provided).

One thought: I have malloc stack logging enabled and was curious if this might lead to memory accumulation that is unrealistic otherwise. At this point it seems like there's no real-world / non-debugger issue based on my testing, but as a relative rookie at memory management I am uncomfortable saying Xcode is giving me a false positive. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It does consume a crap ton of DISK memory (Writes to it). I just spent 20hrs+ trying to figure out why my app was taking 1GB in "Document and Data" space without doing any work.
[malloc log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNleW.png)